# Uniform path with different separators in Java

Tags: java, path

I have a path in input with not uniformed separators.

Example:

- `path/to/file\example.txt`

or

- `\\path\to\file/example.txt`

How can i uniform separators on the basis of the first part of the path in Java?

Comment: can't you use something like this to avoid "\" or "/" separators? `Path path =           Paths.get("path", "to", "file","example.txt");`

Comment: I have no control on the input I receive

Comment: Basically, if that's the issue you can use "`/`" this.

Comment: I can't always use "/" because if my path is \\path\to\file/example.txt , it has to become \\path\to\file\example.txt

Comment: So these are not actually used as paths by your program, but are strings you read and write?

Comment: Can you run `replace` for that symbol in Java?

Comment: What if you read the string, search for one of the two symbols, once you find one of them you store it and with a switch case you replace all the symbols with the one you stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

This is the method i use to fix the path:

```
private String uniformPath(String path) {
    String result = path;
    String[] splitted = path.split("[\\/\\\\]");
    
    if(path.startsWith("\\")) {
        result = String.join("\\", splitted);
    }else if (path.startsWith("/")) {
        result = String.join("/", splitted);
    }else if (path.indexOf("/") > 0 || path.indexOf("\\") > 0) {
        if(path.indexOf("/") < path.indexOf("\\")) {
            if(path.indexOf("/") != -1) {
                result = String.join("/", splitted);
            }
        }else {
            if(path.indexOf("\\") != -1) {
                result = String.join("\\", splitted);
            }
        }   
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `string.replace("\\", "/");` and then `string.replace("//","/");`. This will replace every "\" or "" with "/". if you want a different standard, change the code to replace the "/" with for example the OS specific seperator.